# Future Provider Stuck In loading state

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am using a future provider to display a login page on load and then a loading indicator on loading. Here is my future provider

```
final loginProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, UserInput input) =>
ref.read(authRepositoryProvider).doLogin(input.email, input.password));
```

In my UI I have this....

```
class LoginScreen extends HookWidget {
   final TextEditingController emailEditingController = TextEditingController();
   final TextEditingController passwordEditingController =
       TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     var userInput =
     UserInput(emailEditingController.text, passwordEditingController.text);

     final login = useProvider(loginProvider(userInput));

     return login.when(
       data: (user) => Login(emailEditingController, passwordEditingController),
       loading: () => const ProgressIndication(),
       error: (error, stack) {
         if (error is DioError) {
         return Login(emailEditingController, passwordEditingController);
       } else {
          return Login(emailEditingController, passwordEditingController);
       }
     },
  );
 }
}
```

here is my doLogin function.

```
@override
  Future<dynamic> doLogin(String email, String password) async {
    try {
       final response = await _read(dioProvider)
          .post('$baseUrl/login', data: {'email': email, 'password': password});
       final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(response.data);
     return data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
       return BadRequestException(e.error);
    } on SocketException {
      return 'No Internet Connection';
   }
 }
```

I would like to know why it's stuck in the loading state. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `family` creates a new instance of the provider when given input. So in your implementation, any time your text fields change, you're generating a new provider and watching that new provider. *This is bad.*

In your case, keeping the `UserInput` around for the sake of accessing the login state doesn't make a lot of sense. That is to say, in this instance, a `FamilyProvider` isn't ideal.

The following is an example of how you could choose to write it. *This is not the only way you could write it.* It is probably easier to grasp than streaming without an API like Firebase that handles most of that for you.

First, a StateNotifierProvider:

```dart
enum LoginState { loggedOut, loading, loggedIn, error }

class LoginStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<LoginState> {
  LoginStateNotifier(this._read) : super(LoginState.loggedOut);

  final Reader _read;
  late final Map<String, dynamic> _user;

  static final provider =
      StateNotifierProvider<LoginStateNotifier, LoginState>((ref) => LoginStateNotifier(ref.read));

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    state = LoginState.loading;
    try {
      _user = await _read(authRepositoryProvider).doLogin(email, password);
      state = LoginState.loggedIn;
    } catch (e) {
      state = LoginState.error;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> get user => _user;
}
```

This allows us to have manual control over the state of the login process. It's not the most elegant, but practically, it works.

Next, a login screen. This is as barebones as they get. Ignore the `error` parameter for now - it will be cleared up in a moment.

```dart
class LoginScreen extends HookWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key, this.error = false}) : super(key: key);

  final bool error;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final emailController = useTextEditingController();
    final passwordController = useTextEditingController();

    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: emailController,
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: passwordController,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await context.read(LoginStateNotifier.provider.notifier).login(
                  emailController.text,
                  passwordController.text,
                );
          },
          child: Text('Login'),
        ),
        if (error) Text('Error signing in'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You'll notice we can use the `useTextEditingController` hook which will handle disposing of those, as well. You can also see the call to `login` through the StateNotifier.

Last but not least, we need to do something with our fancy new state.

```dart
class AuthPage extends HookWidget {
  const AuthPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final loginState = useProvider(LoginStateNotifier.provider);

    switch (loginState) {
      case LoginState.loggedOut:
        return LoginScreen();
      case LoginState.loading:
        return LoadingPage();
      case LoginState.loggedIn:
        return HomePage();
      case LoginState.error:
        return LoginScreen(error: true);
    }
  }
}
```

In practice, you're going to want to wrap this in another widget with a Scaffold.

I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but thought it might be helpful to see another approach to the problem.

Comment: Thanks  it actually works. I just get a texteditingcontroller was used after been disposed.